# Reading xml stream

Tags: xml, xmldocument, xelement, betfair

Sorry to be asking such similar question again, I am trying to read the following XML document:

```
<markets currency="GBP">
  <market id="2908368" nextId="2908395">
    <status>ACTIVE</status>
    <commissionRate>2.5</commissionRate>
    <marketType>ANY_NUMBER_OF_WINNERS</marketType>
    <selections type="MainBets">
      <selection id="658442">
        <name>Player 1</name>
        <resource href="https://api.betfair.com/rest/v1/selection/tradeActivity
           ?username=sampleuser&marketId=2908368&selectionId=658442"
           responseType="selectionTradeActivity" title="Trade Activity"/>
        <status>IN_PLAY</status>   <!-- THIS IS THE VALUE I WANT -->
        <amountMatched>0.0</amountMatched> 
        <bestAvailableToBackPrices/>
        <bestAvailableToLayPrices/>
      </selection>
    </selections>
  </market>
</markets>
```

There are 4 players each with a  value that I want, but I can only get the same status, not each players individual status. Please can someone help me. Many many thanks

Comment: what programming language? what previous, similar question?

Comment: eeek what have i done to my question?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1160259/reading-xml-stream
this was the previous question, and the language is vb.net using visual studio 8

Comment: it's your current question not the previous

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use xpath here is an example

```
 XmlDocument xmlDoc;
     XmlNode     xmlNode;
     String      xpathExpr;

     xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
     xmlDoc.LoadXml( "<?xml version='1.0'?><root><person><name>Martin Fowler</name></person><person><name>Kent Beck</name></person><person><name>Dave Astels</name></person></root>" );

     xpathExpr = "/root/person[name='Martin Fowler']";
     xmlNode = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode(xpathExpr);
```